# Abbreviate serialization in .Designer

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, typeconverter

I have a custom control with a property of type `Foo`. I created an `UITypeEditor` for this class.

This works well and results in designer code like:

```vb
Dim Foo1 As PropertySerialization.Foo = New PropertySerialization.Foo()
Me.FooControl1 = New PropertySerialization.FooControl()
Me.SuspendLayout()
'
'FooControl1
'
Me.FooControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 56)
Me.FooControl1.Name = "FooControl1"
Me.FooControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(188, 136)
Foo1.A = 3
Foo1.B = "World"
Me.FooControl1.Something = Foo1
Me.FooControl1.TabIndex = 0
Me.FooControl1.Text = "FooControl1"
```

The `Something` property is of type `Foo` and as you can see the designer creates a new object `Foo1` explicitely.

My question is: Can I tell the designer to rather create the foo object inline using the `With` keyword like:

```vb
'
'FooControl1
'
Me.FooControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 56)
Me.FooControl1.Name = "FooControl1"
Me.FooControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(188, 136)
Me.FooControl1.Something = New Foo() With {.A = 3, .B = "World"}
Me.FooControl1.TabIndex = 0
Me.FooControl1.Text = "FooControl1"
```

I would like this to avoid clutter in the designer file when more complex types are to be created.

Answers in both C# or VB.NET are much appreciated.

Comment: A typeconverter will get you part way there.  Designer serialization is VS's job, and it does it how it sees fit.  You may be able get it to at least use a ctor overload though

Comment: That's true. I had implemented this (but scrapped it for this example) but I ran into the problem, that VS then *only* used the constructor and disregarded any additional properties. That might have been an implementation issue though, as I'm not very well versed in these manners.

Comment: the final True/False for the `InstanceDescriptor` indicates whether there are more props to serialize

Comment: Oh, i have overlooked that. Thanks I will check this again

Comment: It still creates an explicit temp var so it only gets you part way, the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` setting on the other props might be a factor too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Designer (VS) is going to write it out how it wants and a great deal depends on how your `Foo` type is built and what it inherits from.  But in general, you can provide a `TypeConverter` and at least get a bit shorter form using constructor params.

This is done by responding to `InstanceDescriptor` in `CanConvertTo` and `ConvertTo`:

```vb
<Serializable>
<TypeConverter(GetType(FooConverter))>
Public Class Foo
    Inherits ??????

   <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
   Public Property Name As String

   <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
   Public Property Value As Integer

   Public Sub New(newName As String, v As Integer)
        Name = newName
        Value = v
   End Sub

    ' simple constructor
    Public Sub New()
        Name = "New Foo"
        Value = 0
    End Sub
End Sub
```

The `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute value of `Hidden` tells VS not to bother serializing that property.  The intention is to handle it via the overloaded constructor.  The TypeConverter:

```
Friend Class FooConverter
    Inherits TypeConverter

    ' designer serialization will check to see if 
    ' there is a converter available
    Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                    destType As Type) As Boolean
        If destType = GetType(InstanceDescriptor) Then
            ' Yes I Can!
            Return True
        End If
        Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                        info As CultureInfo, value As Object,
                                        destType As Type) As Object

        If destType = GetType(InstanceDescriptor) Then
            Dim f As Foo = CType(value, Foo)

            ' prepare a constructor info
            Dim ctor As Reflection.ConstructorInfo

            ' the ctor wanted, is the one which takes a string, and an Integer
            ctor = GetType(Foo).GetConstructor(New Type() _
                          {GetType(String), GetType(Integer)})

            ' return Instance Descriptor built from ctor info and 
            '   an array of the current values for the ctor
            Return New InstanceDescriptor(ctor,
                        New Object() {f.Name, f.Value}, False)

        End If
        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, info, value, destType)
    End Function

End Class
```

The above is spelled out for clarity, but you can use shorthand:

```
Return New InstanceDescriptor(GetType(Foo). _
                              GetConstructor(New Type() _
       {GetType(String),
       GetType(Integer)}),
       New Object() {f.Name, f.Value}, False)
```

The designer code result will still be an explicit temp object, but a bit more compact, and any *other* properties would stell be set one by one:

```
Dim Foo1 As Prj.Foo = New Prj.Foo("Ziggy", 43)
```

Note that the trailing `Boolean` parameter indicates whether VS should look for more properties.  The combination of that `Boolean` and the `DesignerSerializationVisibility` value on a property will determine if VS serializes the values or your TC handles it.  Any value would wish to persist, should either be handled by your TypeConverter or be set to `.Visible`.

Finally with no info on the custom control or the real `Foo` type it is hard to know how to apply some of the details (what's serializable etc).

Excerpted from [Enhanced CollectionEditor Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) which covers simple TCs and designer serialization.

Personally, it seems like a lot of extra work provided whatever VS will normally do will work.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems that even the MS controls result in explicit declaration of the objects. I think you have made it as short as possible and your CodeProject article seems very interesting and I will read this next.